# I can't seem to find out why I keep getting the error "Invalid method declaration; return type required"

Tags: java, maven, swing

I am trying to make field of UUID type...

```
public class Music {
    private final UUID singerID;
    private final UUID musicID;
   
    Singer() {
        this.singerID = UUID.randomUUID();

    }
    
    Music() {
        this.musicID = UUID.randomUUID();
    }
}
```

And I keep getting the error "invalid method declaration; return type required" at `Singer() {` I am very new to java been like 2 weeks, so if you could go slow on me it would mean a lot to me!

Comment: What is `Singer()` supposed to be? If it's a method, it needs a return type. If it's a constructor, it needs to have the same name as the class it's in. Did you mean to have another class called `Singer`?

Comment: @khelwood I did, I tried that, and it always says "constructor Music() is already defined in class ....." so it dosent work...

Comment: @PoTheBox that's because you already have one. If it's there for no reason just remove it. The point is: what were you trying to do? Why was `Singer()` there in the first place?

Comment: @khelwood Im trying to create 2 fields singerID & musicID while both of them being of type UUID and then return them...

Comment: Then initialise both your fields in one constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the constructor syntax for Singer() when the class is Music.

Change your code to and remove Singer() constructor,

```
public Music() {
   this.musicID = UUID.randomUUID();
   this.singerID = UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

Comment: Correct and upvoted, but I think the endgame would be to not have a `singerID` field in the class, but rather a whole `Singer`. (of course this is pure speculation on my part)

Comment: hey thanks guys, what if I wanna set a getter and setter methods to that so I can return it etc..?

Comment: You can add a `Singer` variable in the `Music` class and move the `singerID` and `Singer()` constructor to the `Singer` class.

Comment: @PoTheBox then don't use final to the UUIDs. You can use setters.

Comment: @JosephKohilan so `private UUID musicID` & `private UUID singerID` but then I am just really confused how i can use setters and getters for the UUID's in this case, I understand how to use setters and getters in strings and int's but cant get the hang of UUID's, could you please help further?

Comment: If you use setters then everytime someone calls the setter method then a new UUID will be set. If that's what you want then here is the snippet, `public void setSingerId() { this.singerID = UUID.randomUUID();}` and getter is already present above.